# Get XMLList stuff dynamically in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I've a XMLList like:

```
<parent>
    <one>
        <child id="1" />
        <child id="2" />
    </one>
    <two>
        <child id="3" />
        <child id="4" />
    </two>
</parent>
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
trace(_LIST._loc_1.child[0].@id);
```

Where the _loc_1 would be "one" or "two".
Is this possible with the getDefinitionByName() to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDefinitionByName` will not help you here, use only `square bracket []` to get the node you want using it's name :

```
var myNodeNameInAVariable:String="two";
myXML[myNodeNameInAVariable]...
```

*Working example based on your question:*

```
var _LIST:XML=
<parent>
    <one>
        <child id="1" />
        <child id="2" />
    </one>
    <two>
        <child id="3" />
        <child id="4" />
    </two>
</parent>;

var _loc_1:String="two";

trace(_LIST[_loc_1].child[0].@id);
```